# Exception Handling in WebFlux publisher

Tags: java, spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I'm wondering why the following way of WebFlux subscription DOESN'T cause a compilation error:

```
@Test public void handlingSubscriberError() {
        
List l = new ArrayList();
l.add("a");
    Mono.just(l)
          .subscribe(x -> {
           throw new Throwable();
           }, e -> log.error("Error occurred:", e));
}
```

whereas this one DOES, and suggests surrounding with a try/catch block:

```
    @Autowired private PersistenceService writer;

    @Test public void handlingSubscriberError() {
            
    List l = new ArrayList();
    l.add("A");
    Mono.just(l)
       .subscribe(x -> {
       writer.persistTo(x, "B", "C");  <== Unhandled exception type Throwable. 
      }, e -> log.error("Error occurred:", e));
   }
```

What's the point of having an overloaded `subscribe()` with the error consumer as a second parameter when one is still forced to add a try-catch by the Java compiler?  Or am I missing something?  Is there a proper idiom for this in WebFlux?

Comment: The first snippet does cause a compilation error because  `Throwable` is a checked exception in Java.

Comment: Are you saying that the overloaded `subscribe()` can only be used for handling the `RuntimeException`s even though its signature explicitly states that the parameter inherits from `Throwable`?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot throw checked exceptions(such as `Throwable` or`IOException`) from the subscriber. The `subscribe()` method takes a `Consumer` function, without any exception declarations. However, Reactor provides the [`Exceptions`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/index.html?reactor/core/Exceptions.html) utility class  which can wrap any checked exception into an unchecked exception, as follows:

```java
Mono.just("test")
    .subscribe(x -> {
        try {
            throw new Throwable("Error occurred:");
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            throw Exceptions.propagate(e);
        }
    }, e -> log.error("Error occurred: ", Exceptions.unwrap(e)));
```

The `Exception.unwrap` is used to get the original checked exception.